# Measure of Similarity Between Scatter Data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, similarities

So I have two scatter data. I would like to determine the similarity between the two scatter plots. What is the good recommended measure that can be used in this case? Is there is anything simpler then fitting Gaussian Mixture Model and obtaining KL divergence between the two?

Updated as per the comment from @whuber: The context behind similarity is that there are regions the points tends to become dense and the regions where the points are pretty sparse. So are two scatter similar in that sense of being dense in certain specific region and sparse in the other.

[image]

[image]

---

Data as requested:

```
dx1 [-0.09218436873747504, -2.0, -2.0, 0.8376753507014025, 0.3326653306613223, -0.7014028056112225, -2.0, 2.0, 2.0, -0.8537074148296595, -2.0, 0.669338677354709, 0.3967935871743484, 1.166332665330661, 0.06813627254509003, -0.2765531062124249, 0.07615230460921829, 0.7174348697394786, -1.3026052104208419, -2.0, 0.8136272545090177, -1.342685370741483, -1.503006012024048, -1.342685370741483, 1.4148296593186371, 2.0, -0.6613226452905814, -0.29258517034068143, 2.0, -0.9579158316633267, 1.2945891783567132, -2.0, -1.8557114228456915, 0.24448897795591185, 2.0, -0.7254509018036073, 1.4549098196392785, 0.2525050100200401, -0.6132264529058118, 0.3807615230460919]
dy2 [-0.02204408817635284, 1.9579158316633265, -1.0, -1.0, 1.5010020040080159, -1.0, 3.0, -1.0, 1.4609218436873745, 1.5010020040080159, 1.0200400801603204, 0.6352705410821642, 3.0, 1.4609218436873745, -1.0, 0.9478957915831663, 2.222444889779559, -0.21442885771543096, 2.2705410821643284, -0.2064128256513027, 2.166332665330661, -0.7114228456913828, 1.4609218436873745, 3.0, -0.6392785571142285, 2.1182364729458913, -0.342685370741483, 1.7174348697394786, 0.8356713426853706, 0.8917835671342684, 0.8837675350701402, 0.42685370741482953, 2.4869739478957915, -0.4949899799599199, -0.41482965931863736, 2.102204408817635, 1.9258517034068134, 0.939879759519038, 0.410821643286573, 0.21843687374749488]
dx2 [-0.09218436873747504, -2.0, -2.0, 0.444889779559118, 0.9338677354709417, 2.0, -0.6372745490981966, 2.0, -2.0, -0.7735470941883769, 0.41282565130260496, -2.0, 0.701402805611222, -0.004008016032064354, 2.0, 0.13226452905811614, -2.0, 0.6452905811623246, -0.7094188376753507, -0.08416833667334678, -1.2705410821643288, 1.1262525050100196, -0.14028056112224463, 1.2705410821643284, 0.23647294589178358, -0.6533066132264531, 0.028056112224448704, 2.0, -1.3587174348697395, 2.0, -1.12625250501002, 2.0, 0.06813627254509003, 0.00400801603206391, 1.3346693386773545, 0.973947895791583, 0.07615230460921829, 0.5410821643286572, -0.2765531062124249, -1.406813627254509]
dy2 [-0.02204408817635284, 1.9579158316633265, -1.0, 1.533066132264529, -1.0, 1.4529058116232463, -1.0, -1.0, 3.0, 1.4048096192384767, 3.0, 0.8116232464929858, 0.4348697394789578, 2.2705410821643284, 3.0, -1.0, -0.12625250501002017, -0.26252505010020044, -0.23847695390781565, 0.8597194388777554, 3.0, 1.973947895791583, 3.0, 0.9639278557114226, 0.13026052104208397, 0.5070140280561122, -0.43887775551102204, -0.2705410821643287, -0.6072144288577155, 0.6112224448897794, 2.198396793587174, 2.286573146292585, -0.038076152304609256, 0.01002004008016022, -0.4228456913827656, 3.0, 0.41883767535070127, 2.4789579158316633, -0.27855711422845697, 1.1162324649298596]
```

Comment: There are myriad possible answers, depending on what these scatterplots represent and what "similarity" is intended to measure.  Please include that essential information in your question.

Comment: @whuber I added the context that you asked.

Answer (score 1):

I would try [Bhattacharaya distance](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bhattacharyya_distance). You can calculate it as follows:
$$BC(p,q) = \int \sqrt{p(x) q(x)}\, dx$$
where $p(x), q(x)$ - multivariate densities of two scatter. You can use [empirical distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Definition_for_two_random_variables).

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the notion of similarity. We can still use the formula you provided right. Can you please suggest the library that calculates this distance?